# Do you need to upload .ipa file if you want to change your title in the app store?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

My app is live on App Store. If I want to change metadata (title, keywords..), do I need to upload new .ipa file?

Answer (score -1):

Depend what specific data you want to change.

If you need more information check this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1)

Comment: Although this is potentially quite a good answer, it is essentially a "link only" answer. You should include some information from your links so that if the information behind the links is ever changed/lost, the answer still makes sense. See [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @JamesWebster i know. When I answer this question I thought in writing as a comment, but I prefer include link to apple documentation. I add some specific comment about fields he asked.

Comment: You can add links in comments. Indeed I did in my previous comment. The format is `[link text](http://the.link.com)`

Comment: Your edit has made the answer both worse, and now wrong, some meta data can be changed. Additionally, why have you added "Title" and "keywords"

Comment: Why downvote? The answer respond exactly what he ask. Check edit answer.

Comment: I only down voted after the edit. See my previous comment.

Comment: @JamesWebster I don't understand you. So what is the clear answer for you. You can help more adding a better answer than just downvote.

Comment: @JamesWebster anyway I return to original answer.

Comment: you seem to be missing the point. The original answer is bad. The edit made it worse by introducing wrong information. A good answer will contain all the information to answer the question and *supplement* it with links.